# SMS security App - Database connection

Tags: android, sms, android-emulator, database-connection

I am developing an SMS security application for Android. My application requires account for users so I'll be using SQLite Database. I have already created tables but I don't know how to connect it to the emulator. Please do help in this. Thanks!

Comment: If you are asking how to connect to sqlite tables in android ? Please read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting an answer so that you can close this question

Use [Content - Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) to connect to your SQLite Db